# sudo service snapd start

Tags: snap

Job for snapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status snapd.service" and "journalctl -xeu snapd.service" for details.

Comment: Providing output (in your question) of `systemctl status snapd.service` would be a good start.